# Use the return value in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method which returns a string. I want to use this string in a thread.

```
private string Serialno()
{
    if (cbSerials.SelectedValue!=null)
    {
        string serial = cbSerials.SelectedValue.ToString();
        return serial;
    }
    else
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

The thread,

```
private void CallAdb(string a, string b, string c, int x, int y, FormWindowState windowstate = FormWindowState.Normal)
{
    var filename = "cmd.exe";
    var arguments = "/C " + a + " tools\\adb " + Serialno() + " " + b;
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = filename,
        Arguments = arguments,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };
    var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };

    process.Start();

    string s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    ToViewer(s, c, x, y, windowstate);
    process.StandardOutput.Dispose();
}
```

I know the is something like:

```
if (InvokeRequired)
```

But after 2 hours searching and trying, I do not get it.

Comment: I don't see anything that is threaded here...?

Comment: I call the CallAdb this way:

                        var thread = new Thread(delegate() { CallAdb(a, b, titel, width, height, windowstate); });
                        thread.Start();

Comment: And where is the output that you are trying to get, and where do you want to return it to? Is it in the `ToViewer` call?

Comment: are you getting any exceptions when calling Serialno()

Comment: I am trying to get the return value Serialno() and paste it in:
var arguments = "/C " + a + " tools\\adb " + **Serialno()** + " " + b;

@faljbour: Yes, I am getting a "System.InvalidOperationException", can't accses the ComboBox value from another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
//* declare a delegate function
public delegate string SerialnoDlg();

//* modify your Serialno this way
public string Serialno()
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    SerialnoDlg dlg = new SerialnoDlg(this.Serialno);
    this.Invoke(dlg);
    return String.Empty;
  } 
  if (cbSerials.SelectedValue!=null)
  {
    string serial = cbSerials.SelectedValue.ToString();
    return serial;
  }
  else
  {
    return String.Empty;
  }
}
```

Comment: I get 3 errors:

Error 1:   Delegate contructor is invoked with 0 arguments.  --> SerialnoDlg dlg = new SerialnoDlg(); 


Error 2:  Cannot resolve method 'Invoke(method group)'  --> this.Invoke(Serialno);

Error 4:   Return value is missing. --> return;

Comment: Edited the first comment

Comment: I made some changes, try again

Comment: Only one error left: Delegate constructor is invoked with 0 arguments.
I did it: SerialnoDlg dlg = new SerialnoDlg(); Changed to SerialnoDlg dlg = new SerialnoDlg(Serialno);

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things in this code:

1. You call UI-related method in thread code(`Serialno()`). Instead, add a parameter to your `CallAdb()` signature and just invoke thread like this: `var thread = new Thread(delegate() { CallAdb(a, b, titel, width, height, windowstate, Serialno()); }); thread.Start();`
2. You'll probably need to use `InvokeRequired`, or rather `Invoke()` method later in your `ToViewer()` method. Essentially, when accessing the UI from separate thread in WinForms, you need to `this.Invoke(()=>your.code.goes.here();)` See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?rq=1) for more details.